Editing format for Syncfusion tooltip
Is there any way to edit the tooltip so that it shows a date
```
<e-chart-tooltipsettings enable="true" header="SWMM Data"
                         format="${series.name}<br>Date: ${new Date(point.x).toLocaleDateString()}<br>Time: ${point.x}">
 ```

Because the date in this setting does not work. When hovering, it shows SWMM Data, the series name, and then this specific string text ${new Date(point.x).toLocaleDateString()} and then the time for the last.
